# Code coverage is not being reported - Sonarqube 4.3.2

Tags: installation, sonarqube

I have installed Sonarqube 4.3.2 on Linux Redhat, JDK 1.7_51 and used following plugins:

- Checkstyle [checkstyle]  2.1
- Cobertura [cobertura]    1.6.2,Java [java]   2.3
- PMD [pmd]    2.2
- SCM Activity [scmactivity]   1.7.1
- Scm Stats [scmstats] 0.3.1

Running `mvn sonar`  on java projects reports all other metrics except code coverage. What am i missing?
Earlier ran into java squid error with `cobertura plugin 1.6.1`, once i upgraded to 1.6.2 went past the error but still code coverage is not being reported.

Comment: Are you generating cobertura report files prior to run sonar analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

Sonar has removed support for code coverage. you need to do coverage analysis on your own or by some tool and import these reports into sonar.
Please refer this : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin

This can be the case for cobertura as well. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I got it to work calling out cobertura explictly as part of the build jobs in jenkins.

Comment: Any ideas why the overall code coverage is vastly different between the 3.5.1 version and latest sonar version implementations?